# I executed a virus, but Windows 7 didn't ask for permission

Tags: windows-update, virus

There was an executable file on my USB, of course, the extension was hidden by the operation system and the icon was the same as a music folder has. Curiosity led to clicking... Later I checked the file on virustotal.com and almost all the antiviruses recognized the file as a virus. The first submission of the virus was in 2016. I have no antiviruses installed and Windows Defender was turned off.

The questions are:

Why didn't Windows 7 ask for permission?

Did keeping the operation system up to date help prevent the virus from activation?

If I download a new file from the Internet or compile my projects in Visual Studio, Windows always asks before executing

Comment: I highly recommend changing the Windows option which hides extensions for known file types. It's always one if the first things I change on a new system.

Comment: “Why didn't Windows 7 ask for permission?” - The UAC prompt is only displayed if the executable request elevated permissions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things, as you don't say whether you were expecting an "insecure file" prompt or a UAC prompt.

1. FAT32 formatted USB sticks lack support for Alternate Data Streams which is where Windows stores data regarding the security zone the file is downloaded from so "this was downloaded from the internet" data is missing.
   Lacking the all important security zone information Windows did not know that the file is from a potentially unsafe location. You insert a drive, it assumes you trust it. It then executes whatever you tell it to.
2. Not all viruses need administrator rights to execute and gain administrator privileges. They can potentially exploit loopholes or bugs to elevate themselves.
   Not knowing what virus you executed makes it tricky to say what it could have done. As you had no antivirus blocking it then it could actually have done whatever work it needed and it could have downloading some remote payload and started running that. Depending on how the C&C servers and virus were written there is a very small but non-zero chance that this happened.

Keeping your system up to date is no guarantee that you are safe.

Use anti-virus/anti-malware and practice safe browsing habits, even on USB devices.